# Make a "go back" button in Next.js

Tags: next.js

How to make a "go back" button with Next.js? It seems that "next/router" does not support go back.

```
<Button onClick={() => Router.BACK()}>Back</Button>
```

Comment: You can use Router.back() or you can even call window.history.back()

Comment: Where can I find the reference of "next/router"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<Button onClick={() => Router.back()}>Back</Button>`

Comment: Where can I find the reference of "next/router"?

Comment: @JimJin you can find it in the [official docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerback)

Comment: Great! Thanks. @NagyWesley

Comment: This solution is not good. If you using this solution you can only quickly go back the site before (like the back button in browser).

Comment: what if i copy the url and open it on incognito or send to someone else ? In that case we do not have history